# Jquery detach / attach a part of the detach

Tags: jquery

If we try the example code give on the manual :
https://api.jquery.com/detach/
It works pretty good.

Now i want to reattach just a part of what i have detach. The code is like something like that :

```html
var listeCourante = $(this).children().filter(".spanUnite").detach();

for(var i in listeCourante){
  if(something){
    listeCourante[i].appendTo($(this));
    break;
  }
}
```

And i got the message "TypeError: listeCourante[i].appendTo is not a function".

When i inspect what is the listeCourante[i], it is a DOM élément, so i do not understand why the appendTo() function not exist.

Some idea ?

Thank's

Comment: What is your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You need understand that once you use `deatch()` function, that HTML will remove from DOM, it no longer exists.

If you want to use that de-attached html again, you need to save in a variable.

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msg;//save deatched html here.
    $('#btDetach').click(function () {
        msg = $('p');
        msg.detach();
    });


    $('#btAttach').click(function () {
        $(msg).find('b').appendTo($('#listeCourante li.name'));
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This is somemething here, <b>hi there</b></p>

<ul id="listeCourante">
    <li>Samir</li>
    <li class="name">John</li>
    <li class="name">Ram</li>
    <li>Jaydeep</li>
</ul>

<button id="btDetach">Detach</button>

<button id="btAttach">Attach</button>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but it is not really i need : The idea is to detach in your example all the "li" and reattach just some of them. In your example, you reattach the exact things you have detach.

Comment: @Naeco, code has been updated, 1) It will detach a sentence 2) Reattach to just some of then 3) Reattach only some part from it.  All three requirements are fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

You've done right. You just need to write `$(listeCourante[i])` instead of `listeCourante[i]`.

It's because of the jquery's selector object. It returns an array which has covered by jquery object. If you want to reference an index of this array and use jquery functions, you have to cover the index with `$()` again.

Your code is going to be like this:

```
var listeCourante = $(this).children().filter(".spanUnite").detach();

for(var i in listeCourante){
  if(something){
    $(listeCourante[i]).appendTo($(this));
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your proposition do not work, i got a new error on the line :TypeError: n.createDocumentFragment is not a function[En savoir plus] jquery.min.js:2:69752

Comment: Change your for loop statement. Try to use this, your problem would be solved: for(var i=0; i<listeCourante; i++) {}

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your propositions but it was not totally working.
I have found what to change, see the comments here :

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
 var saveLi2 = null;
 
 
 
 $("#detachGo2").on("click", function(){
  var tmp = $("#theListe2").children().detach();
  if(saveLi2 == null){
   saveLi2 = tmp;
  }
 });
 
 $("#attachGo2").on("click", function(){
  for(aLi in saveLi2){
   if(!isNaN(aLi) && (saveLi2[aLi].innerText.indexOf("a")!=-1)){
    //saveLi2[aLi].appendTo($("#theListe2")); // not work
    $("#theListe2").append(saveLi2[aLi]); // work
    
   }
  }
  //saveLi2.appendTo($("#theListe2")).hide();
 });
 
}); //fin $( document ).ready




//]]>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


The list:

<ul id="theListe2">
<li>aaaaaaaaaa</li>
<li>bbbbbbbbbb</li>
<li>cccccccccccaaaa</li>
<li>dddddddddddddd</li>
<li>cccccccccccccc</li>
<li>ddddddddddddaaa</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="detach" id="detachGo2"/>
<input type="button" value="attach" id="attachGo2"/>
```

Thank's again !!